# Facing "ImagePullBackOff" error when installing PGO

Tags: docker, kubernetes, pgbadger, crunchy-postgresql-operator

I installed (Fresh) PGO following this document : https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/v5/installation/helm/
it got deployed but the pod is in "ImagePullBackOff" state.
and "https://registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/" is not accessible (404), saying that "This container version is no longer available".

Answer (score 0):

I think the images can be found here: https://hub.docker.com/u/crunchydata

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to install PGO following your link and don't have any issue. What do you have when you execute: `docker pull registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/crunchy-postgres:centos8-14.1-0` from a worker node in your cluster if your container runtime is docker .